# PHP Array [Sorting + Grouping]

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can I sort an array with conditions in PHP? 
I want the array sorted by ID then sort by Parent ID **within the ID not after the ID**.
The reasons why doing is to implement this into jQuery TreeGrid.

For example:

```
Array 
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1 //ID
        [1] => TEST //Name
        [2] => 1 //Parent ID
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2 //ID
        [1] => TEST //Name
        [2] => 2 //Parent ID
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3 //ID
        [1] => TEST //Name
        [2] => 3 //Parent ID
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4 //ID
        [1] => TEST //Name
        [2] => 1 //Parent ID
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5 //ID
        [1] => TEST //Name
        [2] => 2 //Parent ID
    )
)
```

After sorting, become like this:

```
Array 
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1 //ID
        [1] => TEST //Name
        [2] => 1 //Parent ID
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4 //ID
        [1] => TEST //Name
        [2] => 1 //Parent ID
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2 //ID
        [1] => TEST //Name
        [2] => 2 //Parent ID
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5 //ID
        [1] => TEST //Name
        [2] => 2 //Parent ID
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3 //ID
        [1] => TEST //Name
        [2] => 3 //Parent ID
    )
)
```

Comment: what have you tried? did you do a search here on SO first before posting? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+sort+multi-dimentional+array

Comment: Are you fetching these data from database?

Comment: @Sougata yea.. its from database

Comment: Then why not sort it when you are fetching? Show the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_multisort ()](http://php.net/array_multisort).

```
//get lists to sort by
foreach ($your_array as $key => $value) {

    $id_array[$key]        = $value[0];
    $parent_id_array[$key] = $value[2];

}

//sort first by `id` ascending, then by `parent_id` ascending
array_multisort ($id_array, SORT_ASC, $parent_id_array, SORT_ASC, $your_array);
```

You can even shorten the above example by using `array_orderby ()`:

```
$your_array = array_orderby ($your_array, 0, SORT_ASC, 2, SORT_ASC);
```

Comment: with this method, it only can sort the ID and the Parent ID is sorted under the ID not within the ID..

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. It will work

```
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $id[$key] = $row[0];
    $parent_id[$key] = $row[2];
}

array_multisort($id,SORT_ASC,$parent_id,SORT_ASC,$data);
```

Comment: with this method, it only can sort the ID and the Parent ID is sorted under the ID not within the ID..